# Why this code does not compile?

Tags: c++, arduino

Perhaps I'm crazy, but this code fails to compile in Arduino IDE 1.0.5 & 1.0.6.

```
class Foobar {};

void myFunction(const Foobar& n) {
}

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

The compiler outputs the following errors:

```
Arduino: 1.0.6 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Mega 2560 or Mega ADK"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=106 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\variants\mega C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp\build5499093930419069947.tmp\Max7219Testing.cpp -o C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp\build5499093930419069947.tmp\Max7219Testing.cpp.o 

Max7219Testing:2: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
Max7219Testing:2: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Foobar' with no type
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Maybe your source file has a stray (control) character?  It compiles fine here: http://ideone.com/AuDEQL

Comment: Post the intermediate .cpp file found in the temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles cleanly here:

http://ideone.com/AuDEQL

```
class Foobar {};

void myFunction(const Foobar& n) {
}

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}

int main() {}
```

If the code is as you've posted, the cause is usually

1) An invisible character (usually a control character) is embedded on one of the previous lines where the error occurs, and the C++ parser is picking it up as a syntax error

or

2) The characters you *are* seeing in your source file are not ASCII, but some "fancified" version of the character (thus either Unicode or some other encoding).  This can happen if you copy and paste from an application that uses the alternate encoding to make the text "look good", for example, a word processor such as MS Word.

I would take the file and inspect it in a hex editor to ensure it doesn't have such characters.

Edit:  The other scenario, which was pointed out in the comments by `Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams` is

3) you could be compiling a different file than the one you have posted.  This seems to be the case for Arduino IDE.

Comment: Nah, it's the Arduino IDE adding extra crap that turns it into not-C++.

Comment: Well, it is a variation of item 1)  :)

Comment: My first impression was that there was some invisible character. Then, I wrote the same code manually in another computer, with a different OS, with the same result.

Comment: It's not an invisible character. Wait until the file I asked for is posted and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Edited the answer to add the Arduino IDE issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my `$DEITY`!

Following Ignacio suggestions, I checked out the final assembled cpp file that Arduino generates and the build system tries to compile:

```
#line 1 "sketch_feb05b.ino"
#include "Arduino.h"
void myFunction(const Foobar& n);
void setup();
void loop();
#line 1
class Foobar {};

void myFunction(const Foobar& n) {
}

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

So the IDE generates the declarations of the functions and puts them in the beginning of the file, before the types are declared.

No invisible symbols after all but a terrible decision of Arduino authors :-(

I wonder whether putting the types in external header files would fix it.